# Is it possible to make a function that receives a JSON parameter in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, stored-functions

I would like to know if it is possible to make a function that receives a JSON parameter in MySQL. Something like it is done in PostgreSQL (attached example).

I need to migrate a PostgreSQL DB to MySQL and there are many such functions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_crud_sls_quotation_concept_types (data json)

RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' 
AS 
$$

DECLARE
"vType"         integer := data ->> 'type';
"vId"           bigint  := data ->> 'id';
"vDescription"  varchar := data ->> 'description';
"vStatus"       integer := data ->> 'status';
"vUserId"       integer := data ->> 'userId';

BEGIN

IF "vType" = 1 THEN -- Data Insert  

        INSERT INTO tbl_sls_quotation_concept_types(description, status, "createdBy")
        VALUES("vDescription", "vStatus", "vUserId");
        
    RETURN TRUE;
    
ELSIF "vType" = 2 THEN -- Data Update

        UPDATE tbl_sls_quotation_concept_types 
        SET "description"   = "vDescription",
            "status"        = "vStatus",
            "updatedBy"     = "vUserId", 
            "updatedAt"     = current_timestamp
        WHERE id = "vId";
    
    RETURN TRUE;
    
ELSIF "vType" = 3  THEN -- Data Delete
        
        UPDATE tbl_sls_quotation_concept_types 
        SET status = 0 ,
            "updatedBy" = "vUserId", 
            "updatedAt" = current_timestamp
        WHERE id = "vId" ;
        
    RETURN TRUE;

END IF;

END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a stored function can accept an input parameter of the JSON data type:

```
mysql> delimiter $$
mysql> create function myfunc(data json) returns varchar(10) deterministic 
  begin 
    declare val varchar(10); 
    set val = json_extract(data, '$.val'); 
    return val; 
  end$$
mysql> delimiter ;
mysql> select myfunc('{"foo": 1, "val": "bar"}');
+------------------------------------+
| myfunc('{"foo": 1, "val": "bar"}') |
+------------------------------------+
| "bar"                              |
+------------------------------------+
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html says:

> *type:*
>
> Any valid MySQL data type

Comment: MySQL does have a [`->>` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path) but it also expects a JSON path, not a key name.

Comment: There are many other differences between PostgreSQL syntax and MySQL syntax that will require changes to the PostgreSQL function shown in the OP's question. My answer is only about the specific question about whether a function can accept JSON as a parameter.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks, I looked for ->> and didn't find it somehow

Comment: @BillKarwin do you know how can I send a NULL when I select the function? Something like: select myfunc('{"foo": 1, "val": NULL}');

Comment: @BillKarwin I know I can just not send it, but I need to do it.

Comment: Yes, what you show is exactly how you do it. I just tested on my local MySQL and it works.